# How to prove functions are odd and even

Tags: calculus, functions

Show that any function f on [-a,a] where a is a positive constant, can be written as the sum of an even and an odd function?

Comment: Look at $g(x) = (1/2)[f(x) + f(-x)]$. What can you say about $g$?

Answer (score 1):

***First step:***

Assume that $f = g + h$, $h$ even and $g$ odd.
Then
$$f(x)= g(x) +h(x)\\
f(-x) = g(x) - h(x)
$$
this gives you $$
g(x) = \frac12(f(x) + f(-x))\\
h(x) = \frac12(f(x) - f(-x))\\
$$hence $(g,h)$ is unique.

***Second step:***

just check the hypothesis, that is:
$g$ is even, $h$ is odd. This proves existence of $g,h$.

***Conclusion:***

$$
\exists ! (g,h)\ \  \forall x : g(x) = g(-x), h(x) = -h(-x), f(x) = g(x) + h(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $$H(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$$
$$F(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$$

Note that $H$ is even, and $F$ is odd, also $H(x)+F(x)=f(x)$